# easyToolTip jquery shows two tables

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code :

```
<td><table class="inner">
                        <?php 
                        foreach($inner_info as $k=>$v)
                        {
                            if($v['type']=="pardakhti"){
                                echo "<tr><td title='<table>
                                <tr>
                                <td><strong>نوع پرداخت</strong></td>
                                <td>".convert_pay_type($v['pay_type'])."</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td>تاریخ</td><td>".$v['date']."</td></tr>

                                </table>'>".$v['amount']."</td></tr>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<tr><td>0</td></tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

and the jquery part is :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  $("td").easyTooltip();
    $("td").easyTooltip({       tooltipId: "easyTooltip2",  });      });
```

and CSSes are :

```
#easyTooltip2{
padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #195fa4;
    background:#195fa4 url(bg.gif) repeat-x;
    color:#fff;
    }
#easyTooltip2 table{
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#easyTooltip2 td{

    font-size: 10px;
    border:none;

}
    .inner td {
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: none;

    padding: 10px;
}
```

but it appears wrongly, the screenshot link : [image: The screeenshot]

what's wrong here? 
as you can see there is an underlay table with wrong width and height and padding that should completely be removed . why is there  two tables?

thank you in advance

Comment: This looks incorrect: <tr><td title='<table> ... </table>'>.

Comment: you're right , but according to easytooltip examples , I put it into title tag, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

That is just plain wrong. A whole table as an atrribute??

```
<td><table class="inner">
        <?php 
        foreach($inner_info as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v['type']=="pardakhti"){
                echo "<tr><td><table>
                <tr>
                <td><strong>نوع پرداخت</strong></td>
                <td>".convert_pay_type($v['pay_type'])."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>تاریخ</td><td>".$v['date']."</td></tr>

                </table>'".$v['amount']."</td></tr>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr><td>0</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</td>
```

Even with this, there are two tables coming up.

I suggest this markup

```
<td>
        <?php 
        foreach($inner_info as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v['type']=="pardakhti"){
                echo "<strong>نوع پرداخت</strong>".
                convert_pay_type($v['pay_type']).
                "<span>تاریخ</span>".
                $v['date'].
                $v['amount'];
            }
            else{
                echo "0";
            }
        }
        ?>
</td>
```

Comment: thank you , so what's the solution or is there any suggestion to use instead of easytooltip?

Comment: @BehroozA, See my update, I suggested a markup upgrade. I dont understand the language, so Please dont be offended regarding the markup.

Comment: Yes, get rid of the <table> stuff in the title.  Just put in your tooltip text.  You can mark it up with <strong>, <em>, etc and with the css you provide.